# CAST TO DATE into JSON_TABLE DEFINITION - Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

I have the next code:

```
INSERT INTO TMP_VDD_JSON
VALUES (
    200, 2, 4010,
    '{
        "Cuenta": [
            {
                "persona": {"nombre": "Pedro", "documento": "9876543A", "fecha-nacimiento": "02/02/1982", "ciudad": "Barcelona"}
            }
        ]
);
```

I want to convert it into JSON_TABLE.

```
SELECT jt.NOMBRE, jt.DOCUMENTO, jt.FECHA_NACIMIENTO, jt.CIUDAD
FROM TMP_VDD_JSON tmp,
JSON_TABLE(tmp.JSON_OBJ, '$.Cuenta[0].persona'
    COLUMNS (
        NOMBRE PATH '$.nombre',
        DOCUMENTO PATH '$.documento',
        **FECHA_NACIMIENTO DATE PATH '$."fecha-nacimiento",**
        CIUDAD PATH '$.ciudad'
    )) jt
```

The main purpose is to cast the field FECHA_NACIMIENTO **implicit** to DATE, INTO clause of JSON_TABLE.

¡**I NO WANT** TO DO IT INTO SELECT STATEMENT!
There are any way?

Comment: If the data is stored in a table, then yes, you need to execute a SELECT.

Answer (score 2):

> There are any way?

Yes, if your date is in ISO 8601 format:

```sql
CREATE TABLE tmp_vdd_json(
  JSON_OBJ CLOB CHECK ( json_obj IS JSON )
);

INSERT INTO TMP_VDD_JSON
VALUES (
'{"Cuenta": [{"persona": {
    "nombre": "Pedro",
    "documento": "9876543A",
    "fecha-nacimiento": "1982-02-02",
    "ciudad": "Barcelona"
}}]}'
);
```

Then your query (if you add the missing closing single-quote) works:

```sql
SELECT jt.NOMBRE, jt.DOCUMENTO, jt.FECHA_NACIMIENTO, jt.CIUDAD
FROM TMP_VDD_JSON tmp,
JSON_TABLE(tmp.JSON_OBJ, '$.Cuenta[0].persona'
    COLUMNS (
        NOMBRE PATH '$.nombre',
        DOCUMENTO PATH '$.documento',
        FECHA_NACIMIENTO DATE PATH '$."fecha-nacimiento"',
        CIUDAD PATH '$.ciudad'
    )) jt
```

And outputs:

> | NOMBRE | DOCUMENTO | FECHA_NACIMIENTO | CIUDAD |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | Pedro | 9876543A | 02-FEB-82 | Barcelona |

If you have a non-standard date format then, no, it will not work and you need to perform the conversion in the select list like this (adjust the format model for your data):

```sql
SELECT jt.NOMBRE,
       jt.DOCUMENTO,
       TO_DATE( jt.FECHA_NACIMIENTO, 'YYYY-MM-DD' ) AS FECHA_NACIMIENTO,
       jt.CIUDAD
FROM   TMP_VDD_JSON tmp
       CROSS APPLY JSON_TABLE(
         tmp.JSON_OBJ,
         '$.Cuenta[0].persona'
         COLUMNS (
           NOMBRE           VARCHAR2(20) PATH '$.nombre',
           DOCUMENTO        VARCHAR2(20) PATH '$.documento',
           FECHA_NACIMIENTO VARCHAR2(20) PATH '$."fecha-nacimiento"',
           CIUDAD           VARCHAR2(20) PATH '$.ciudad'
         )
       ) jt
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=074d8507ff75797533f140cc74a7a884)*

Comment: So I no have the ISO format, I must to convert ONLY in SELECT stmt?

Comment: @VahramDanielyan I cannot immediately find any documentation where they state it but, JSON conversions to `DATE` in Oracle appear to only support ISO 8601 formatted dates (I checked and it does not work with the default `NLS_DATE_FORMAT`). So: no ISO format = no implicit conversion = do it in the select list.

Comment: Thanks, I see that is not possible.

Comment: There are a few references to the ISO format in the Oracle documentation, both for generating JSON from SQL data and for generating SQL values from JSON. The closest I could find is here (search for the word "date" on that page; also notice the difference between *date* and *timestamp*): https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/adjsn/json-path-expressions.html#GUID-AEBAD813-99AB-418A-93AB-F96BC1658618

Comment: [The json_value page](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/JSON_VALUE.html) says "must be a character value that can be implicitly converted to a DATE data type" which implies it would use NLS settings, [but that doesn't work either](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=87244b357903d0b1983cd42229043593). Seems to be a doc bug that it doesn't make it clear it only allows ISO.

Comment: Thanks so much!  The non-standard date example was a massive help!